# Can we create a C++ string object from char pointer where the operations on the string object reflects to the source char pointer?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, stdstring

I've been trying to use C++ string class rich methods (find_first_of, replace) for some string processing for a task.

And i created a wrapper file around the above mentioned code, where it can be included in 'C' source files and get the functionality.

> **strUtils.h**

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void doTheStringWork(char *inStr, unsigned beginLoc);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

> **strUtils.cpp**

```cpp
#include "strUtils.h"
/*some standard includes here*/

void doTheStringWork(char *inStr, unsigned beginLoc) {
    std::string inStr_s(inStr);

    /* Doing some processing with the string object inStr_s*/  
    /* .......*/
    /* Done */

    return;  

}
```

And now i'm stuck with one problem which cannot be solved without making copies as far as i know. So, i seek your help in this.

The problem is i need to get the changes done by `doTheStringWork` function back at the caller's place. You may say take `.c_str()` value as return from func or get a copy somehow.  That approaches works well but for my tasks it becomes very slow approach since the string can be too long and i might require it to process recursively.

In plain words: can we create a string object around a char pointer where i can use all string functions and the char pointer reflects all these changes.  If such thing cannot be achieved using standard library could someone provide an approach how can i achieve my goal here.

Comment: Since C++ 17, string_view. Allows to create a string based on given allocated data (another string, or char*). However this is for a non mutable one.

Comment: Unless you control how the original character array was allocated, any solution that requires a reallocation implies that you are also left with a useless array that you can't know if/how you should free it.

Comment: `std::string_view` could probably work for you.

Comment: @SergeyA but Michael told the object becomes immutable.
And also i cannot use c++17 already due to other project restrictions.

Comment: Additionally, any operation that performs a reallocation may invalidate copies of the original data pointer (supposing that it updates even one particular copy), which are not so unlikely to be hanging around if you're working with bare pointers in the first place.

Comment: I would guess that this is impossible because `std::string` internals should be implementation defined. (Any language lawyer here to confirm?) The reason is that some implementations might want to use small string optimizations. You therefore can only count on `.c_str()`, nothing else...

Comment: Thank yo all for sharing your views, for this task i could follow @Radosław's method provided in below answer would do best job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution is to dump C, use C++ and get away from whole mess. But since you probably can't do that, next best solution is to create your own C visible struct and some C visible functions (essentially PIMPL), define those in C++ source (so you get benefits of `std::string`) and use them from C. Something like this.

In `strUtils.h` header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
typedef struct cpp_string cpp_string;

cpp_string *cpp_string_create(const char *txt, int size);
void cpp_string_free(cpp_string *);
cpp_string *cpp_string_add(cpp_string *, cpp_string *);
... // all operations you need

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In C++ source (`strUtils.cpp`):

```
#include <string>
struct cpp_string {
  std::string str;
  cpp_string(std::string str): str(std::move(str)) { }
};
extern "C" cpp_string *cpp_string_create(const char *txt, int size)
{
  return new cpp_string{ std::string{ txt, (size_t)size } };
}

// fill operations here
// since this is C++ file, just use std::string without copying
```

Now, when you want to use it, you do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    cpp_string *s = cpp_string_create("qwerty", 6);
    // do something with s

    // dont forget to free s
    cpp_string_free(s);

    return 0;
}
```

This sidesteps whole can-i-overwrite-someone-elses-memory (no, you can't, unless you want to have weird, wierd problems) by creating your own data.

Comment: This approach is the best for me compared to all other approaches i tries. Just one copy would be made if i program carefully. Thank you so much @Radoslaw